# Change the image source with fade jQuery fade effect on multiple list items

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-ui, hover, jquery-hover

I want to change the single image's source with multiple images on multiple hovers from the list items with fade effect.

So I am trying this:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sub_menu li").hover(function(){
        $(".changesrc").fadeOut(1000, function() {
            var path = "images/";
            $(".changesrc").attr("src",path + $(".sub_menu1 li a").attr("id") + ".jpg");
        }).fadeIn(1000);
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="sub_menu">
  <li><a id="image1" href="">Faucets</a></li>
  <li><a id="image2" href="">Showers</a></li>
  <li><a id="image3" href="">Bathwares</a></li>
  <li><a id="image4" href="">Flushing Systems</a></li>
  <li><a id="image5" href="">Bath Accessories</a></li>
  <li><a id="image6" href="">Necessaries</a></li>
  <li><a id="image7" href="">Newly Introduced</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="menu_thumb">
   <a href="">
     <img class="changesrc" src="images/image1.jpg" >
   </a>
</div>
```

But it is only changing the image with first id. How can I replace the image name with each id? or any other simple dynamic way out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/abamid/1/edit

```
$(function(){  // DOM ready shorthand

  $(".sub_menu li a").hover(function(){
      var ID = this.id;                       // get anchor ID
      $(".changesrc").stop().fadeOut(400, function() {
          this.src = "images/"+ ID +".jpg";
          this.onload = function(){           // make sure img is loaded
             $(this).fadeIn(400);             // fadeIn
          };
      });
   }); 

});
```

Comment: @AvtarNanrey you're welcome :D always glad to save the day! ;) thx

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sub_menu li").hover(function () {
        var anc_id = $('a', this).attr('id'); // Cache the id

        $(".changesrc").fadeOut(1000, function () {
            var path = "images/";
            $(".changesrc").attr("src", path + anc_id + ".jpg").load(function() {
              $(this).fadeIn(1000);
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```